# how to display image in recycler view android studio

Tags: java, android, image, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview in my app in which I want to display an image in an imageview. I am storing the path of the image that I want to display in a sqlite database as a TEXT field, the problem is that it does not display the image in the imageview, being that I correctly read the route from the database, I know this since I am printing the route with a Toast.
I hope you can help me. Greetings

my code:

```
public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.ViewHolder> implements View.OnClickListener {
    private List<ListDebates> data;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;
    private View.OnClickListener listener;
    public int id;
    public String title_text;

    public void filteredListTest(List <ListDebates> item){
        this.data = item;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public ListAdapter(List <ListDebates> itemList,Context context){
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data = itemList;
        this.context = context;

    }

    //onCreateViewHolder enlaza el adaptador con el archivo xml
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ListAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cardview,null);
        view.setOnClickListener(this);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }
    //onBindViewHolder establece la comunicación entre el adaptador y la clase ViewHolder
    // .Aquí se envía la información que se quiere mostrar,para ello se ocupa el objeto holder
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ConexionSQliteHelper conn=new ConexionSQliteHelper(context,"lala",null,5);
        Toast.makeText(context,"la imagen es"+image_discuss,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //  Glide.with(this).load(personPhoto).override(200, 200).into(image_user);
        Picasso.get().load(data.get(position).getImage_debate()).into(holder.image_post);

    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }
    public void setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener listener){
        this.listener=listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(listener!=null){
            listener.onClick(v);
        }
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView image_post;
        TextView title,user,arguments,count_viewer,count_discuss;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            image_post = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_debate);
            

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: "I am storing the path of the image that I want to display in a sqlite database " -- where did this path come from?

Comment: what happens is that the app has a user profile, so the user can change the profile image of the app by clicking on a button, every time the user clicks on the button the profile image is changed by loading the route of the new image selected from the image gallery (also overwriting it in the database by the path that was previously)

Comment: "every time the user clicks on the button the profile image is changed by loading the route of the new image selected from the image gallery" -- most likely your problem lies here. You might consider editing your question and expanding your [mcve] to show how you are obtaining and storing this "path".

Answer (score 0):

You are saving the user's gallery image path and this is incorrect. If the user deletes the photo from the gallery, you are unable to recover that image. Either you save the image in your app's private folder or you save the images on a remote server.